# RDLC Reports: use Column caption in table header

Tags: visual-studio, reporting, rdlc

I have a table in a `RDLC report`, and I'd like to use the `Caption` property of the underlying data source columns to display the column name in the table header, rather than having to manually input the column names.

Is this possible? I know I can probably use an `expression` to do this, but I don't find any info on how to fetch the `Column.Caption` property from an expression. Any hints??

Comment: Where did you see this "Caption" property? I'm not aware of anything of this sort for rdlc reports. What you describe (text for field name) would appear in the column header when you are "picking" your fields in details row, but I don't think you can do it at run-time. Maybe you can provide scenario when it's needed, so we could think of some solution?

Comment: I mean the "Caption" property on the columns of a DataTable, which I'm using as data source for the report and that is supposed to be used exactly for holidng a description/title for the column. I would like to bind the table header labels to those Caption properties, rather than having to input them manually. The scenario is that I have cases when I have to generate the same exact report but only with different header labels, seems absurd having to create a new report just for this minor change.

Comment: I think you would have to work with expressions in the table header to set different values for column name depending which report is being printed.

Comment: I believe this is where a subreport could come in use.

Comment: @Oceans: I don't see how frankly... can you elaborate?

Comment: Instead of creating an exact copy of your original report, you can (for example) place the table in a subreport.
However you'd still have to create multiple subreports, but this could be less work than the complete report.

Comment: If it's really only the displayed names of the columns that you wish to change, you could use parameters or a second datasource that you give to the reporter.

Comment: @Oceans: yes, as you point out: if I can't "bind" to the property of the column and I have to use extra data to set the names there are much easier ways (i.e: passing a second dataset that just contains the columns names) rather than messing with subreports. I was just wondering if there was a way without relying on extra data, since the Caption property is already there, purpose-build for that use. Isn't there a way to access it via an expression?